# How fast does eyelid close when eyelash is triggered?

Tags: neuroscience, eyes, anatomy, human-eye

What is the reaction of blinking like when an unexpected piece of wood or something hits an eyelash and then an eyeball?

A piece of stone flew into my eyeball when we knocked a wall down, and it hit the white area. Another time, I walked into a piece of wood in the dark, and my eyelid closed faster than I was walking so it protected my eye.

So it got me thinking. Is there a fast neural network in between the lash and the the lid contractors, so that the eyelid can close very fast when the lash is contacted unexpectedly? How fast does the reaction happen?

Answer (score -1):

The human eye is thought to react about 1/24 of a second, but I'm not sure how fast it is when it touches an eyelash

Comment: Thought by who? based on what? Please [edit] your posts to conform to the standards of this site.